# Reinstall when building and running in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, lua, moai

I am building an iOS app and running it on a connected device. During debugging, additional config files are present in the app. However, if I delete those config files from Xcode and then do a build and run, they are still present on the device (these are lua files that we write our game in). How can I force Xcode to uninstall the previous version of the app, i.e. do a complete clean build when installing? Cleaning the project and targets and deleting Derived Data seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly assume that you can't. Installing the app on the device copies files to the device, but does not delete files already present on the device.

(I had a similar problem when I converted a nib-based view controller to a programmatically created view controller. The nib file was still in the app bundle, leading to strange error messages.)

The only way to remove the entire bundle is to delete the app on the device.